# Question about my code for returning longest word

Tags: python

Write a python function named longest, that takes two arguments (you can safely assume that all arguments will always be strings). 
When this function is called, it should determine which string is longer, and return that string.

My code:

```
def longest(word1, word2):
    if word1 < word2:
        return word2
    else:
        return word1
```

When this function is called, it should determine which string is longer, and return that string.

Comment: `<` compares strings in lexographic or dictionary order, it doesn't compare the length

Comment: In the future, please remember to actually ask a question. You forgot to do that this time; you just posted a bunch of code and requirements.

Answer (score 1):

The `<` operator doesn't compare the length of strings, but rather what order they would sort alphabetically. Instead try `len(word1) < len(word2)`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `<` for length comparison of length of strings, you need to create your own class which should be subclass of built-in `str`. Lets give this subclass the same name as `str`.

`<` operator is implemented using a method called as `__lt__()` and in your subclass you need to implement this method. You can implement `__le__()` as well for `<=` operator. You might need to override other operators according to your requirement.

So your subclass definition will look like this:

```
class str(str):
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return len(self) < len(other)

    def __le__(self, other):
        return len(self) <= len(other)
```

Now you can use your method to get the longest word as:

```
def longest(word1, word2):
    if str(word1) < str(word2):
        return word2
    else:
        return word1
```

`str(word1)` is important here because by default string creation will use build-in `str` class but you should use your subclass `str` class. This method is rather complicated, so you can just use `len(word)` to get the length of the word and use this to find the longest string.